# How to update value in anonymous list in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list which is anonymous type and I've `tagId, isTagSelected & tagName` in it. What I want is want to add 4th property based on some condition

Code:

```
var tagDetails = tagIdList.Select((x, i) => new { tagId = x, isTagSelected = tagSelectionList[i], tagName = tagList[i] }).ToList();
```

Result:

```
{tagId = 1, isTagSelected = true, tagName = "a"}
{tagId = 2, isTagSelected = false, tagName = "b"}
{tagId = 3, isTagSelected = true, tagName = "c"}
```

What I want is, if `tagName` is `a` then add `Size = "S"` else `string.empty` or `null`. How can I achieve this? I tried following approach which is, add Size in all of them and then remove from unwanted place but it is not working.

Code:

```
var tagDetails = tagIdList.Select((x, i) => new { tagId = x, isTagSelected = tagSelectionList[i], tagName = tagList[i], itemSize = itemSize }).ToList();
```

Result:

```
{tagId = 1, isTagSelected = true, tagName = "a", Size = "S"}
{tagId = 2, isTagSelected = false, tagName = "b", Size = "S"}
{tagId = 3, isTagSelected = true, tagName = "c", Size = "S"}
```

I tried `foreach` loop but I can change read only property. Is there anyway that I can remove `Size` from "b" & "c"?

Expected Result:

```
{tagId = 1, isTagSelected = true, tagName = "a", Size = "S"}
{tagId = 2, isTagSelected = false, tagName = "b", Size = "" or null}
{tagId = 3, isTagSelected = true, tagName = "c", Size = "" or null}
```

Comment: All properties of anonymous types are read-only. You'll have to figure out a way to produce the instances with the value already correct. This may mean a second query where you produce a new set of values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im not at a VS instance but it seems like this would work.

```
var tagDetails = tagIdList.Select((x, i) => new 
        { tagId = x,
          isTagSelected = tagSelectionList[i], 
          tagName = tagList[i], 
          Size = tagList[i] == "a" ? "S" : null 
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: This what I was looking for. Thank you